# Need help interpreting string's characters using perl

Tags: perl, winapi, character-encoding

What exactly is this output (which characterset) and how do I convert it to something that makes sense?[image]

```
use Win32::API;

$EnumProcesses= new Win32::API( 'psapi', 'EnumProcesses','PNP');

$aBuffer = " " x 4096;
$bBuffer = " " x 4096;

$EnumProcesses->Call($aBuffer,4096,$bBuffer);
print $aBuffer,"\n",$bBuffer,"\n";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm asking because mucking around with the Win32 API is not for the faint of heart, and there's probably a CPAN module that will do what you want without fuss.

Comment: I don't think the solution to this is to use another module, man. Clearly, I am trying to get the Win32::API to work with perl.

Comment: using Win32::API is not a goal in itself; you are trying to do *something* with the Win32::API. What is your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read the [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation and the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) linked therein? It seems that you're not dealing with character data at all. EnumProcesses fills `$abuffer` with N 4-byte (or DWORD) records, one for each process. This 4-byte value is just a number, not 4 characters.

If you want to get more information about a particular process, you need to feed this 4-byte number (referred to in the Win API docs as a "process identifier") into a function such as [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or PrintProcessNameAndID.

Here's code which displays the results as 4-byte little-endian numbers:

```
use Modern::Perl; # strict, warnings, 5.10 features
use Win32::API;

my $EnumProcesses= new Win32::API( 'psapi', 'EnumProcesses','PNP');

my $process_ids_packed = " " x 4096;
my $num_processes_packed = " " x 4; # you don't need 4096 here.

$EnumProcesses->Call($process_ids_packed,4096,$num_processes_packed);

my ($num_processes) = unpack "V", $num_processes_packed;
my @process_ids = unpack "V$num_processes", $process_ids_packed;

for (@process_ids) {
    say;
}
```

And here's the results:

```
C:\Users\pgp\Documents\src\tmp>perl winapi.pl
0
4
252
392
464
472
520
536
544
596
692
748
780
788
912
964
412
456
908
1116
1212
1228
1460
1492
1520
1528
1576
1724
1740
1748
1988
2028
312
2288
2544
2592
2756
3004
3116
3216
3340
3048
2792
1320
2868
3760
2404
4196
2692
4084
1768
538976288
538976288
538976288
538976288
538976288
 [... lots more lines ...]
538976288
538976288
538976288
538976288
538976288
538976288
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::API; 

my $EnumProcesses = new Win32::API('psapi','EnumProcesses','PNP'); 
my $process_ids_packed = "\0" x 4096; 
my $num_processes_packed = "\0" x 4;  

$EnumProcesses->Call($process_ids_packed,4096,$num_processes_packed); 
my ($num_processes) = unpack "V", $num_processes_packed;

my $buffer = "\0" x $num_processes; #Allocate buffer of proper-size 
$EnumProcesses->Call($buffer,$num_processes,$num_processes_packed); 

print "Number of processes: ",$num_processes/4,"\n";

my @process_ids = unpack "V$num_processes", $buffer; 

for (@process_ids) { 
    print $_,"\n";
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Why are you calling EnumProcesses a second time? You only need to call it once, as in my solution.

Comment: Your solution has a fixed buffer for the process ids. Mine doesn't. It is so done to instantiate an array of PID that doesn't have '53976288' in it and also is not constrained by the buffer.

Comment: @seaworthy 53976288 is in the claimed-valid portion of the buffer. using `unpack "V$num_processes"` extracts only `$num_processes` entries from `$buffer`. In the case that there are more than 1024 processes, `$num_processes` will still equal 1024 (as the documentation states) so you won't fetch any more than my code will. Finally, you need 4 bytes per process, so the space required is `$total_number_of_processes * 4`.

Comment: also, to get my attention add @Philip to the start of your comment; this pings my inbox when I log in.

Comment: @Philip-Potter I am just looking for a way to drop of the 5376288 and to avoid getting into a situation where I pull more information than a buffer can fit. To be honest, I don't think my code accomlishes the latter. It does the former when the buffer is larger than the data available. Can you speak of the code directly? I do not see where $total_number_of_processes is coming from. When you mention that $num_processes will stil equal 1024, are you also implying that the rest of info will be omitted? Thanks.

Comment: `$total_number_of_processes` is not in the code, but I used it because `$num_processes` only tells you how many processes were returned by EnumProcesses; the total number may be higher. The [EnumProcesses documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) discusses this carefully. Also, you won't pull more information than the buffer can fit if you report the size of the buffer correctly.